# Excel create an array from non-stacked cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sumproduct(array1,array2) is an excel formula that performs the dot product.

=`Sumproduct({1,2,3},{7,0,5})`
results in 1*7 + 0*2 + 5*3 = 22

I want to replace the first array by values stored in non-stacked cells ( for example: A1,A3,B7) I tried 
=`Sumproduct({A1,A3,B7},{7,0,5})`
but it doesn't work. It seems I can't create an array from non-stacked cells.

Can you please help me create an array of non-stacked cells in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as an array formula entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(CHOOSE(ROW(1:3), A1, A3, B7), CHOOSE(ROW(1:3), 7, 0, 5))
```